# How can I trigger Web API from a controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that gathers information and saves it to a database. After the save but before I return the view from this action, I want to send a GET request (with a string parameter) to a Web API to trigger additional processing work. The additional processing will be a long running task and I will not be waiting for the response.

How can I trigger an API and proceed with returning the view without awaiting a response from the GET request?

Here is the signature of the method from which I'm hoping to trigger the API:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> XYZ(XYZViewModel model)
{
     //
     // Saving data to db...
     //

     <-- Trigger API here -->

     return View("XYZResult", vm);
}
```

Comment: Just call it and do not await it. Fire and forget

Answer (score 0):

```
using RestSharp;



    public Task TriggerAPIAsync(XYZViewModel model)
    {

        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("API_URL");

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

        request.AddParameter("param_name", "value");
         ....
        request.AddParameter("param_name", "value");


        request.Method = Method.POST/GET;
        client.Execute(request);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

and then call it

```
public ActionResult XYZ(XYZViewModel model)
{
     //
     // Saving data to db...
     //

     APIAsync(model);

     return View("XYZResult", vm);
}
```